# C++ template class = typename

Tags: c++, templates

what `template <class = typename T::type>` means? Can you refer me to some blog, specification describing this?

The question originaly came from explanation of [sfinae on cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

```
template <typename A>
struct B { typedef typename A::type type; };

template <
  class T,
  class   = typename T::type,      // SFINAE failure if T has no member type
  class U = typename B<T>::type    // hard error if T has no member type
                                   // (guaranteed to not occur as of C++14)
> void foo (int);
```

Comment: `class   = typename T::type` is a template parameter with no name, but with a default value.

Comment: its an anonymous parameter whose only purpose is to render the template invalid in case `T` has no `type`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, I'll explain `typename T::type`. This is simply the access of a member type. Here's an example of accessing a member type:

```
struct foo {
    using bar = int;
};

int main() {
    foo::bar var{};

    // var has type int
}
```

So why the `typename`? It simply means we want to access a type. Since we are in a template and `T` is an unknown type, and `foo::bar` could also mean accessing a static variable. To disambiguate, we denote that we effectively want to access a type by explicitly typing `typename`.

Okay, now what does the `class =` means?

The `class =` means the same thing as `typename =`. When declaring template type parameters, we introduce then using `class` or `typename`:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct baz {};
```

But as any parameters in C++, the name is optional. I could have wrote this and the following is completely equivalent:

```
template<typename, typename>
struct baz {};
```

Also, you know in function parameters, we can specify default values? Like that:

```
void func(int a, int b = 42);

int main () {
    func(10); // parameter b value is 42
              // We are using default value
}
```

We can also omit parameter names:

```
void func(int, int = 42);
```

Just like function parameters, template parameters can have it's name omitted, and can have a default value.

```
template<typename, typename = float>
struct baz {};

baz<int> b; // second parameter is float
```

---

### Putting it all together

Now we have this declaration:

```
template <
    class T,
    class   = typename T::type,   // SFINAE failure if T has no member type
    class U = typename B<T>::type // hard error if T has no member type
                                  // (guaranteed to not occur as of C++14)
> void foo (int);
```

Here we declare a function that takes an int as parameter, and has three template parameter.

The fist parameter is a simple named parameter. The name is `T` and it's a type template parameter. The second is also a type parameters, but it has no name. However, it has a default value of `T::type`, which is a member type of `T`. We are explicitly telling the compiler that `T::type` must be a member type of `T` by specifying `typename`. The third parameter is similar to the second.

This is where SFINAE kicks in: when a default parameter is used, but `T::type` as as a member type don't exist, how can you assign the second template parameter to that? We can't. If `T::type` don't exists, we cannot assign the second template parameter. But instead of making it an error, the compiler will simply try another function, because there is a chance another function would be callable.

This is quite similar to simple overloading. You have the  `f` function. It takes a `float` parameter, an another overload that takes a `std::string`. Imagine you call `f(9.4f)`. Does the compiler choke because a `std::string` is not constructible from a `float`? No! The compiler ain't stupid. It will try another overload, and will find the `float` version and call it. In SFINAE a similar analogy can be made. The compiler won't stop because there's some overload somewhere that needs an undefined type in a template parameter. It will try another overload.